# Linear Algebra: Complex Vector Space is also a Real Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm trying to prove that if V is a complex vector space then it is also a real vector space. How should I approach this?

Comment: Apply the definition. A vector space over a field has to be a commutative group under addition and acted on by the field by scalar multiplication in a way that ensures the distributive property.

Comment: This follows because $\mathbb{R}\subset \mathbb{C}$. If you take a real scalar $\alpha$ then it is also an element of $\mathbb{C}$ so the properties of vector space follow by definition.

Comment: If all of the above is true for the complex numbers, of course it is true for the reals.

Comment: @Willy.K Thanks so much for the helpful explanation! I was making it way harder than it needed to be, but you made it clear.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: I think this is just the complexification.